# Roots of a quadratic equation involving summations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, optimization, discrete-optimization

How do you find the roots of a quadratic equation involving summations like these:

$$\sum_k^n f_k v_k^2 -\sum_k^n c_k v_k - \sum_k^n d_k = 0$$

Where $v_k$ is the variable and $n$ is arbitrary

Comment: For $n\geq 2$ there can be infinitely many solutions, such as a circle

Comment: You can have an infinite number of solutions, for example 

$$x^2+y^2-1=0$$

(unit circle) has an infinite number of points